# How do I display clickable wordpress blog post titles in an UITableView for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, wordpress

I am working on a iOS application in which I would like users to be able to access a table view list of blog post titles. The blog is self-hosted and runs on the Wordpress platform. The blog is linked to a twitter account so that each time a new post goes live, a new tweet is generated with the post title and the url. I was thinking that I could retrieve the twitter feed and insert the tweets into my table but I don't know if that's the easiest/best way to do it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to setup an RSS to UITableView instead of bringing in the twitter API to do the job for you. If you keep the UITableView dependent on the Twitter API, you are inducing an additional, unwanted level of data dependency. Use RSS and update the UITableViews. You could possibly use this: http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/rss-reader-part-4-setting-up-the-uitabbar-and-uitableview-with-delegates/ although I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.